# Предложение с разными видами связи

Tags: предложение

Помогите объяснить почему перед словами*и лес точно..." нет запятой.Предложение:"Через четверть часа, когда над нашими головами разразилась гроза и лес точно застонал от раскатов грома, у нас в палатке весело горел огонёк".

Answer (score 2):

Здесь запятая не нужна потому, что "когда над нашими головами разразилась гроза" и "лес точно застонал от раскатов грома" - однородные придаточные, соединенные сочинительным союзом "И". Признаком того, что это именно однородные придаточные (а не присоединение новой части главного) является наличие общей части ("когда").    
(-------------)   
§ 119
...    
~2. Между двумя придаточными, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами и, или, либо, да (в значении «и»), запятая не ставится (при этом подчинительный союз или союзное слово может и не повторяться): Подходя к дому, я вспомнил, что неподалеку в еловом перелеске с можжевельником не раз спугивал старого петуха-черныша и еще там жила матка с одним молодым петушком (Пришв.) — две придаточные части изъяснительные, соединенные союзом и; Точь-в-точь такую же жалость вызывала у нее и мать, Зинаида Витальевна, когда, забыв про своих продавщиц, парикмахерш и массажисток, усталая, укладывалась на ночлег или когда учила девочку завязывать бантики (Бел.) — две придаточные части времени, соединенные союзом или.  
(-------------)    
(Лопатин)
http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=375

Answer (score 1):

Это СПП, союз И связывает однородные придаточные времени с союзом КОГДА (союз во втором предложении пропускается). В этом случае запятая не ставится, так как по своим грамматическим свойствам однородные придаточные как бы приближены к однородным членам.